# Select table cell programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Swift, I can select a table cell like this:

```
 let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0);
 tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
```

But trying to call `didSelectRowAt` like this:

```
tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

Which fires this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = categoryListView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CategoryCellView   // error here

    //do other stuff
}
```

and causes this error at `//error here` above:
`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I am using this class for the `CategoryCellView` which is a separate nib:

```
@IBDesignable
class CategoryCellView: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myCategoryView: Category!
    var categoryId: Int?
    var index: Int?
}
```

How can I trigger `didSelectRowAt` here?

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use `selectRow` - that's the recommended way to select a cell programmatically.

Comment: `didSelectRowAt:` is not called after selecting a row programatically (and don't call it yourself). A possible solution is to put the code in `didSelectRowAt:` in an extra method to be able to reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellForRow(at: indexPath)` can return nil if the cell is not visible — and the cell might not be visible immediately after calling selectRow. So I would recommend updating your didSelectRow implementation to avoid the `as!` force-unwrap and be more defensive:

```swift
if let cell = categoryListView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CategoryCellView {
    // do stuff with the cell
}
```

(or maybe use `guard let` if that makes more sense)

I would recommend *not* directly invoking UITableView or UITableViewDelegate functions such as `didSelectRow` (or other UIKit standard delegate functions) from your own code, as it breaks the original design contract of these functions. This can cause buggy or unwanted behavior if you're calling didSelectRow directly on the UITableView object. Instead, write another custom function in your class that implements UITableViewDelegate where you can updating the appropriate UITableViewCell after calling selectRow. You could possibly call this same function from your didSelectRow implementation and thus reuse some code.

Depending on what you need to do with the cell in your didSelectRow method, you could address the programmatic-selection scenario in other ways. For example:

- Within your cellForRowAt implementation, you can check whether `indexPath == tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`, or check `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.contains(indexPath) ?? false`, to determine if the cell about to be displayed is a selected cell. Note that at this moment, the cell's isSelected value may be false. The UITableView will set isSelected to true if needed immediately afterward. Which leads to the second option:
- Implement `override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` in your CategoryCellView, if you just need to update the appearance of that specific table view cell. If the cell is already visible when you call selectRow, setSelected will be called immediately. If the cell is not visible at the time you call selectRow, setSelected will be called on that cell later, immediately after the delegate's `tableView(_:,cellForRowAt:)` is called, when the user scrolls to that cell

Comment: This causes the error, `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CategoryCellView'` so I changed it to, `if let cell = categoryListView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CategoryCellView? ` and everything is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You're close...</s>

Give this a try:

```
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0);
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    self.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

---

**Edit**

As noted (and this can be found in many places), one should never call delegate methods containing `will`, `did` and `should` yourself.

Another approach might be:

```
@objc func simulateSelectRow() -> Void {
    print("sim")
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0);
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    myDidSelectRowAt(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
}

func myDidSelectRowAt(_ tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> Void {
    // do what you want when row is selected
    print("Row:", indexPath.row, "in Section:", indexPath.section, "was selected.")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myDidSelectRowAt(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

This may, or may not, be suitable for your needs - but it could be an option.

Comment: Never ever call delegate methods containing `will`, `did` and `should` yourself.

Comment: In general, I agree. In this specific case... hmmm... maybe?